# retrofit.RetrofitError : 400 Bad Request.. how to debug

Tags: java, retrofit

I am a super noobie to Retrofit and changed existing code of a class to send a list of strings instead of a single string. However with the change I get the above error. The class is defined as :

```
class MyEvent {
    public List<String> orderIds;

    public MyEvent(List<String> orderIds) {
        this.orderIds = orderIds;
    }
 }
```

and then at the calling code for this I have :

```
new MyEvent(orderIds))
```

where orderIds is List

However the moment I use this in my request it fails back and goes into :

```
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
```

How do i figure out what i am doing wrong? Any pointers gladly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Best Way to Debug Retrofit Error Messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071952/the-best-way-to-debug-retrofit-error-messages)

Comment: Can you show us how you make the request? And also, does your server support multiple values for the same parameter?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to enable logging for retrofit, it's easy to do with a library.

Most likely you have a validation response that is being thrown out.

I use 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
Here's a helpful post about how to enable it:
[Logging with Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2)